# Graph layout algorithm for ontologies (directed acyclic graphs)

Tags: layout, graph, igraph, ontology

I'm looking for a way to display an ontology (DAG). Preferably I'd like to generate a structure like:

[image: DAG visualisation]

I've been playing around with the layout algorithms in [igraph](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/igraph/docs/layout) but haven't found anything close to what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are basically looking for a radial tree layout algorithm. igraph includes a tree layout algorithm (the [Reingold-Tilford algorithm](http://reingold.co/tidier-drawings.pdf), but it does not produce radial layouts by default as it lays out the tree in a top-down manner. You can experiment with transforming the layout generated by the Reingold-Tilford algorithm into a radial layout (just use the Y coordinate as the radius and the X coordinate as the angle around the origin). This will probably provide a good starting point, but I suspect that the resulting layout can be improved further by passing it to a force-directed layout (like the Fruchterman-Reingold algorithm) that is able to refine an initial "seed" layout.

*Note:* using the Fruchterman-Reingold layout algorithm out-of-the-box probably wouldn't work because if you don't provide it with a seed layout, then it starts from a random layout. The random layout is probably very far from the optimal tree-like layout and thus it is harder for the Fruchterman-Reingold algorithm to disentangle the crossing edges.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Can you give me any more information about how I might transform the generated Reingold-Tilford layout? I can generate the layout with `layout = layout.reingold.tilford(bsk.dag, root = "CLX0000007063")` which gives me a matrix with X and Y.

Comment: Normalize the X coordinates (the first column) to be between -pi and pi, then construct another matrix where the first column is `cos(layout[,1]) * layout[,2]` and the second column is `-sin(layout[,1]) * layout[,2]`. This performs the transformation from a top-down to a circular layout. Then you can feed this layout into `layout_with_fr` to refine it further.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Its getting there and I'll continue to play around with the layout.